# Decorate data before passing them to templates in Django

Tags: python, django

I hava this kind of confusition when passing data from views to templates. The data is stored in float like this 0.12, and it was displayed like this "12%", so we have to change it like we did below, but here comes the question, what kind of choices shall we choose?
There are two kind of choices, first one is like this:

```
item_list = Items.objects.all()
for item in item_list:
    item.interest_rate *= 100
    item.financing_amount /= 10000
...
return render_to_response("xxxx.html",{'ret': item_list})
```

And the second one is like this:

```
item_list = Items.objects.all()
ret = []
for item in item_list:
    temp = {
        "temp_interest_rate": item.interest_rate *= 100,
        "temp_interest_rate": item.financing_amount /= 10000,
    }
    ret.append(item)
...
return render_to_response("xxxx.html",{'ret': ret})
```

The first one is obviously much more simple, but I think maybe its not a good way to change the database model directly even we did not save it.

I have already convinced my classmate to use the second one for safety, but I haven't convinced myself for that. So is there any experienced Django developer can offer some advice?

Comment: I think 1st one is much more cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `"0.12"` is a *string*, its not a float.

It is perfectly fine to decorate your objects in your view before passing them to the template; adding properties to objects dynamically does not affect the database.

The problem here is that you are modifying a *display detail* in the view. This is not ideal. You should let the presentation layer (the template), decide how something is displayed and your view to send across the "raw" data.

The easiest way to resolve this is to create your own [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), which will format your data correctly at the presentation layer.  You'll note that the [large library of default filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference) all serve the same purpose - to convert data into a format for the presentation layer; which is why the recommended approach would be to create your own filter.